# Boot stops with “Primary master drive - ATAPI Incompatible”

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, bios

I have a [MPC-414](http://www.geeks.com/details.asp?invtid=CLIENTPRO414-MAR-R) computer which was working until the Boot order & compatible drivers were changed in the bios so now when I boot Windows 7 it freezes on a black screen & says:

> Press <kbd>DEL</kbd> to run setup  press <kbd>F12</kbd> if you want to
>   boot from the network press <kbd>F11</kbd> for BBS POPUP  Initializing
>   USB Controllers..Done. 2048MB ok Auto-Detecting Pri Master..IDE Hard
>   Disk  Auto-Detecting Sec Master..ATAPI CDROM  Sec Master: Sony DVD RW
>   DW-D56A PYS1 Ultra DMA Mode-2 Auto-Detecting USB Mass Storage
>   Devices..00 USB mass storage devices found & configured.

Then on the bottom it says:

> Primary Master Drive - ATAPI Incompatible  Press <kbd>F1</kbd> to
>   resume.

And when I try to use the commands listed nothing happens it stays on the black screen. I tried using the CD & it starts but wont read or respond. Is there any way to correct this or bypass it or boot thru another computer?

Comment: Change the BIOS settings back.

Comment: How do I do that? if I cant get anything to work

Comment: You can't get into the BIOS setup? Worst case, reset the CMOS.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in BIOS you have the option somewhere to "reset to default".  For all my computer's BIOS it is F9 --> answer yes and then I press F10 to exit saving changes.  Yours may be different though.

To get into BIOS you have to press F2 or DEL or F8 or F12 (or some other button) after your computer turns on but before your OS begins getting loaded.  Reboot and hammer (tap lightly repeatedly) on the button until BIOS pops up.

Or try a [GRUB Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/) or [Boot Repair Disk](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/).